# JMSerializerbundle : deserialize node children with different names

Tags: php, xml, jmsserializerbundle

I have an xml like this :

```
<screen>
    <text id="qs65d4"></text>
    <image id="xcq789"></image>
    <text id="9s8xdf7"></text>
    <button id="q6sd47"></button>
</screen>
```

I need to deserialize it and get an array of "screenobjects" here is what I tried :

```
class Screen {
    /**
     * @Type("array<string, MyBundle\Entity\ScreenObject>")
     * @XmlList(entry = "*")
     */
    protected $objects;

}
```

And my ScreenObject class

```
/**
 * @Discriminator(field = "type", map = {
 *    "text": "MyBundle\Entity\ScreenObjects\Text",
 *    "image": "MyBundle\Entity\ScreenObjects\Image",
 *    "button": "MyBundle\Entity\ScreenObjects\Button"
 * })
 */
class ScreenObject {
    /**
     * @Type("string")
     */
    protected $id;
}


class Text extends ScreenObject{
    /**
     * @Type("string")
     * @XmlAttribute
     */
    protected $id;

    public function getType() {
        return 'text';
    }

}
...
```

I know the wildcard *@XmlList(entry = "*")* is a bit hazardous, but I can't find my solution in the JMS documentation.

Thank for your help.